# Waiting for Table Level lock on AWS Cluster Aurora RDS for SELECT Queries only

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

My team is getting this below error message on AWS Cluster Aurora RDS on reader and writer instances:

Waiting for table level lock

Kindly note:

1. We are NOT USING Lock Tables explicitly anywhere
2. We are NOT USING MyISAM Tables
3. We are NOT USING any Kind of MYSQL Dump

.

```
mysql> show variables like '%innodb_table%';
    +--------------------+-------+
    | Variable_name      | Value |
    +--------------------+-------+
    | innodb_table_locks | ON    |
    +--------------------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> show variables like '%innodb_autoinc_lock_mode%';
    +--------------------------+-------+
    | Variable_name            | Value |
    +--------------------------+-------+
    | innodb_autoinc_lock_mode | 1     |
    +--------------------------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For those who know about this issue - Is there anyway we can replicate the issue on our Testing Node.

Comment: maybe programmatically do a `show engine innodb status` right away when you get that, and see if that shows you anything?

Comment: show engine innodb status doesn't work on the reader instance of Aurora RDS but it works on the writer instance.  I will check it and inform you about it. Thanks!

Comment: I presume that I have found the reason as to why this issue had occurred.  I had changed the setting on the prod system 1 month ago and the "waiting for table level lock" error didn't show up again on the performance insights monitoring tool.  The log_format = TABLE was modified to log_format=FILE.  From then on, it didn't re-occur.  This was the only table that had CSV Engine where all the slow queries were being logged and was being used by our system.  Rest of all production tables that we have is of innodb engine type.